# Trouble understanding Fibonacci Series

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def fibo(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    elif n <= 1:
        return [1]
    elif n <= 2:
        return [0, 1]
    else: 
        fibo_s = fibo(n - 1) # Can someone please explain me this else code
        fibo_s.append(fibo_s[-1] + fibo_s[-2])
        return fibo_s

print(fibo(6))
```

Please help me understand the "else code" I am not able to understand how `fibo(n-1)` will stores `[1,0]`

Comment: In the else statement, you are recursively calling the function ```fibo```.  Using pencil and paper work through the steps of your code if you start with ```fibo(3)```.   If you still have questions, update your question with where you are having trouble.

Comment: It makes a recursive call to get a list containing the first n-1 Fibonacci numbers. It then appends to that the sum of the last and last-but-one of that list, which is the next Fibonacci number. It then returns this extended list.

Answer (score 5):

The `fibo` function is called recursively in the else branch.

If we call `fibo(4)` for instance, the else branch is used. `fibo(n-1)` is `fibo(3)`. Now in *that* recursive call, `fibo(2)` is called. That immediately returns `[0, 1]`.

To this we append the result of adding the last two items in that list. Now `fibo_s` is `[0, 1, 1]`. *This* gets returned to the `fibo(4)` call, which appends to that list the result of adding the last two elements (`1` and `1`) giving a result of `[0, 1, 1, 2]`.

```
fibo(4)
  fibo(3)
    fibo(2) 
    <- [0, 1]
  <- [0, 1, 1]
<- [0, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the classic examples of **recursion**. This is when a function calls itself within its own body.

The fibonacci example is an example of recursion because you are essentially finding results of the same function, just a number lower. Let's look at a more simple example first:

```py
def my_func():
    print("Hello world!")
    my_func()
```

This function recursively calls itself forever. You can think of it as doing the following:

```py
def my_func()
    print("Hello world")
    # called again, does the following: print, and then another call
    print("Hello world")
    # since the function just got called, it will again do the same thing
    print("Hello world")
    ...
```

This function will go on forever, because there is no **base case**. For the fibonacci sequence, the base cases are in this block:

```py
...
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    elif n <= 1:
        return [1]
    elif n <= 2:
        return [0, 1]
...
```

These will prematurely return a value **without recursion** if n is either 0, 1, or 2. So, let's imagine n is 2. Simple: it returns [0, 1].

But what if it was 4? The function would go to the else statement, and then **call `fibo(3)`**, because 3 is 4-1.

So what happens at `fibo(3)`? **It calls `fibo(2)`**. Keep in mind, in the original function of `fibo(4)`, you're still on the `fibo_s = fibo(n-1)` part, because you're waiting for the recursion to happen.

So, after `fibo(3)` calls `fibo(2)`, `fibo_s` is now equal to `[0, 1]`. Then, you take the last two values, add them, append them to the list of `fibo_s`, and return the result. So, now, **fibo(3) returns [0, 1, 1]**.

This result is stored in `fibo_s` in `fibo(4)`. Note how this is the same thing that happens in `fibo(3)`, just with a high level. Then, like it did in `fibo(3)`, you take the last two numbers, add, them, append them to `fibo_s`, and return. So you have `[0, 1, 1, 2]`.

Think of it like this, when you call `fibo(4)`:

```
fibo(4)
   |
   fibo(3)
      |
      fibo(2) # returns [0, 1] as a base case, so the loop ends here, and then operations are done on the upper functions using this result.
```

Comment: _prematurely_ seems like an odd word to use in that context.

Answer (score -2):

```
def fibo(n):
    if n<=0:
        return []
    elif n<=1:
        return [1]
    elif n<=2:
        return [0,1]
    else: 
        fibo_s=fibo(n-1)
        print(fibo_s,"before append fibo(n-1)")
        print(fibo(n-1),"the fibo(n-1)") # Can someone please explain me this else code
        fibo_s.append(fibo_s[-1]+fibo_s[-2])
        print(fibo_s,"after append addition of last two indexes")
        return fibo_s

print(fibo(6))
```

Updated your code so that you can understand how your code flow is working

```
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] before append fibo(n-1)
[0, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3] the fibo(n-1)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] after append addition of last two indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

By this you can understand how your code is working always use print statement in loop, conditions and functions to analyze code

Comment: just putting a string of text usually won't help people. you have to try your best to **explain it**, in simple and easy to understand terms. that's what I was trying to do, and I can imagine being a beginner and ending up getting more confused by your answer.

Comment: Ok ,so we have to explain in layman language in details

Comment: that's generally better, yeah. you can still include what you have at the end of your answer to give them a chance to play around with it, but you also need to explain what everything means to make a good answer